# Identity Matrix should be created without NumPy

Tags: python-3.x, matrix-multiplication, vector-multiplication

I have to implement a few method which sets a matrix to an identity matrix. It sounds easy but I am not allowed to use NumPy.

```py
class Matrix4():
    def __init__(self, row1=None, row2=None, row3=None, row4=None):
        """Constructor for Matrix4
        DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD"""
        if row1 is None: row1 = Vec4()
        if row2 is None: row2 = Vec4()
        if row3 is None: row3 = Vec4()
        if row4 is None: row4 = Vec4()
        self.m_values = [row1,row2,row3,row4]

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of the matrix
        DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD"""
        toReturn = ''
        if self is None: return '0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00\n0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00\n0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00\n0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00'
        for r in range(0,4):
            for c in range(0,4):
                toReturn += "%.2f" % self.m_values[r].values[c]
                if c != 3:
                    toReturn += ' '
            toReturn += '\n'
        return toReturn


    def setIdentity(self):
        """Sets the current Matrix to an identity matrix
        self is an identity matrix after calling this method"""
        row1 = Vec4(1,0,0,0)
        row2 = Vec4(0,1,0,0)
        row3 = Vec4(0,0,1,0)
        row4 = Vec4(0,0,0,1)
        setIdentity.Matrix4()
        return Matrix4(row1, row2, row3, row4)
```

As you can see, we have a class of Matrix4() and I have implemented the method so far. If I try to print out the identity matrix, it fails.
The command

```py
print(Matrix4())
```

prints out the zero matrix. Executing following command

```py
print(setIdentity.Matrix4())
```

tells me that setIdentity is not implemented. What is wrong with my code?

I am open for your suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: What does Vec4() do?

Comment: You need to do, `Matrix4().setIdentity()`

Comment: It doesn't work for me, matt. It says that setIdentity is not defined.

Comment: What method are you allowed to change? You have to remove the line from your method `setIdentity.Matrix4()` that is gibberish and broken.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Now it works fine.

Comment: It works for your print statement, but it doesn't do what the method comment says.

Answer (score 1):

You should really do this in parts because you seem to be missing some concepts.

```
m = Matrix4()
```

Now you have a matrix of all zeros. Next you want to make it an identity matrix.

```
m.setIdentity()
```

Your current implementation is broken in numerous ways.

```
def setIdentity(self):
    """Sets the current Matrix to an identity matrix
    self is an identity matrix after calling this method"""
    row1 = Vec4(1,0,0,0)
    row2 = Vec4(0,1,0,0)
    row3 = Vec4(0,0,1,0)
    row4 = Vec4(0,0,0,1)
    #setIdentity.Matrix4()~
    #return Matrix4(row1, row2, row3, row4)
    self.m_values = [row1, row2, row3, row4]
```

This fixes two problems of the `setIdentity` not being defined, and instead of returning a new matrix, it modifies the existing one.

I will fix your answer code in the following.

```
class Matrix4():
    def __init__(self, row1=None, row2=None, row3=None, row4=None):
        """Constructor for Matrix4
        DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD"""
        if row1 is None: row1 = Vec4()
        if row2 is None: row2 = Vec4()
        if row3 is None: row3 = Vec4()
        if row4 is None: row4 = Vec4()
        self.m_values = [row1,row2,row3,row4]

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of the matrix
        DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD"""
        toReturn = ''
        if self is None: return '0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00\n0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00\n0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00\n0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00'
        for r in range(0,4):
            for c in range(0,4):
                toReturn += "%.2f" % self.m_values[r].values[c]
                if c != 3:
                    toReturn += ' '
            toReturn += '\n'
        return toReturn


    def setIdentity(self):
        """Sets the current Matrix to an identity matrix
        self is an identity matrix after calling this method"""
        #Dont do this either, it is unescessary!
        #m = Matrix4()
        row1 = Vec4(1,0,0,0)
        row2 = Vec4(0,1,0,0)
        row3 = Vec4(0,0,1,0)
        row4 = Vec4(0,0,0,1)
        self.m_values = [row1, row2, row3, row4]
        #No, do do this! this is causing the recursion!
        #m.setIdentity()
        #Stop returning a new matrix!
        #return Matrix4(row1, row2, row3, row4)

m = Matrix4()
m.setIdentity()
print(m)
```

The code to create a matrix and set it to identity should be OUTSIDE of your class. You are using the class at that point. I added comments above the line I remove. I only changed the method setIdentity.

Comment: Your solution doesnt't work for me. It tells me something about RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

Comment: Now it seems to work fine. I must use the commands m=Matrix4() and m.setIdentity() in the Python Interpreter, right?

Comment: Possibly? You can use it in a script or you can use it in an interpreter. Matrix4() creates a matrix, but doesn't assign it to anything. `m = Matrix4()` creates a matrix and then you can use it afterwards. For example if you wanted to make it an identity matrix you could use. `m.setIdentity()` then m is an identity matrix.

Comment: If I use them in the interpreter, everything works fine. If use them in the script, I will get an error which tells me that the recursion length has been exceeded.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing in your script, it shouldn't make a difference the interpreter is like writing the script as you go.

Comment: If I use the code outside the class, I will get an SyntaxError. unexpected indent.

Comment: You should do the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the function **setIdentity** from the class **Matrix4**, you would have to write it in the following way:

```
(class instance).function()
```

Therefore, in your case:

```
print(Matrix4().setIdentity())
```

As for your code:

> print(Matrix4())

It doesn't work because it calls the constructor (**init**) to create the default instance of Matrix4. You would have to modify the init function if you wanted a different matrix as your default.

Comment: This isn't really correct because setIdentity is an instance method. eg you need an instance of a Matrix4 to calll set Identity with.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    print(Matrix4.setIdentity())
TypeError: setIdentity() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'